# Cannot connect CentOS on port 9200

Tags: centos

[image]Hello all,

I cannot connect to my CentOS server on port 9200, the port ElasticSearch uses. This is my iptables file (see image above).

As you can see I tried to open port 9200, but apparently without success. I can curl localhost:9200 on the CentOS server successfully. But when I try to curl 192.168.2.229:9200 (which is the ip address of eth0) I receive an error (curl:(7) couldn't connect to host).

And ofcourse, when I try to connect the address 192.168.2.229:9200 form my windows machine I cannot connect either. Does someone no the problem?

And the netstat results:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is due to your ES instance be listening on localhost only. To change that on a CentOS instance, you can add into the following lines into the file **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml** and restart the service.

```
network :
    host : 192.168.2.229
```

Check more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/setup-configuration.html#settings

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Fixed!